# Implement conversations.create in C#

Tags: c#, slack, slack-api

I am looking at Slack’s documentation on conversations.create and I’m not sure how to integrate it in C#. Do I need to import their Slack API solution into my code to use it? Any help would be great!

Comment: Hey, It looks like you are new here. Welcome to SO. You typically show what work you have done so far on a problem before posing a question. If you can google an answer then your question probably isn't off to a good start. I'm not going to downvote your question but, its all but guarnteed that others will or, that this question will be closed. 

https://github.com/Inumedia/SlackAPI

Comment: Hi Terrance thank you! Yeah that’s true I did a lot of Googling and none of the sources has helped. Don’t get me wrong I would post code if I had code :)

Comment: Did you use the link? I just googled "Slack API C#" and this was at the top. You would just need to add the nuget package and reference the namespace. 
https://github.com/Inumedia/SlackAPI

Comment: If any of the posted answers solved your question please consider marking it as solution by clicking on the checkmark. TY!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a channel with C# all you need to do is make a POST request to the respective API method. `channels.create` will work, but I recommend the newer [`conversations.create`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.create) API method.

There are many way how to you can make a POST request in C#. Here is an example using `HttpClient`, which is the preferred approach. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-http-post-web-request) for alternatives.

Here is an example:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SlackExamples
{
    class CreateChannels
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        static async Task CreateChannel()
        {
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "token", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SLACK_TOKEN") },
                { "name", "cool-guys" }
            };

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://slack.com/api/conversations.create", content);
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(responseString);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateChannel().Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The token you need it kept in an environment variable for security purposes, which is good practice.

Answer (score 0):

you can use httpclient or restsharp (my personal favorite) to call slacks web api.

You'd be calling https://slack.com/api/conversations.create from your application, it's not like an sdk you download.

restsharp code:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "7efd9a78-827d-4cbf-a80f-c7449b96d31f");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer xoxb-1234-56789abcdefghijklmnop");
request.AddParameter("undefined", "{\"channel\":\"C061EG9SL\",\"text\":\"I hope the tour went well, Mr. Wonka.\",\"attachments\": [{\"text\":\"Who wins the lifetime supply of chocolate?\",\"fallback\":\"You could be telling the computer exactly what it can do with a lifetime supply of chocolate.\",\"color\":\"#3AA3E3\",\"attachment_type\":\"default\",\"callback_id\":\"select_simple_1234\",\"actions\":[{\"name\":\"winners_list\",\"text\":\"Who should win?\",\"type\":\"select\",\"data_source\":\"users\"}]}]}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Using the Restsharp 3rd party library for sending a POST request is another viable approach. However your example is sending a message, not creating a channel as requested by OP. Also you don't need the postman or cache-control header.